# does the connection to MySQL auto close when a user is redirected?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using pdo method to connect to the MySQL databases via PHP.

Here are the steps that my page is written to execute.
1) open connection
2) run queries 1
3) run queries 2
4) run queries 3
5) close connection.

Now if I want to redirect a user to a different page using "header('Location new_page.php')" function after step 3 will the connection to the database be auto close since the user left the page? or do I need to close the connection manually before the transfer happens?

thanks

Comment: Google found many results on the subject. The answer is yes, it will. Google search term used "does mysql connection automatically close after redirect?"

Comment: if your script not finished after `header` with `die` or `exit`, then not... step 4 will be execute too...

Comment: also if you use `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT`, then your connection not closed after php execution end, and will reused by next pdo connects

Comment: PHP cleans up when a script terminates, which also closes any open db connections, closes open files, blah blah blah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You don't have to do it , the connection closes automatically at the end of the script.

From the PHP Docs ...

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open
> links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.

This is common for PDO too.

Also, this ...

> with PHP 4's Zend Engine, a resource with no more references to it is
> detected automatically, and it is freed by the garbage collector. For
> this reason, it is rarely necessary to free the memory manually.

To answer your question..

> Now if I want to redirect a user to a different page using
> "header('Location new_page.php')" function after step 3 will the
> connection to the database be auto close since the user left the page?
> or do I need to close the connection manually before the transfer
> happens?

Whenever, you do a header , use an `exit` or a `die` to end the script.

```
die(header("location:somepage.php"));
```

**or**

```
header("location:somepage.php");
exit;
```

Comment: `header` call does not ends php script execution

Comment: First of all.. you cannot have logic after the `header` , you will get a _headers already sent warning in the first place_

Comment: `headers already sent` is about some echoing **before** `header` or cookies setting

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the connection will be closed after the PHP execution finished of that page. In other words, at the end of page loading the connections will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

No, header calling don't stops the script execution

Explain:

```
<?php

//1) open connection 
//2) run queries 1 
//3) run queries 2 
header('Location: /');
//script execution continuous here
//4) run queries 3 
exit();// here php close all your connections
//5) run queries 4 //Unreachable code
//6) close connection.
```